# Correct order of power-rule of derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Let us have a Green's function $G^R$ written in matrix form
$$
G^R(k) = \frac{1}{\epsilon I_2 - H(k) + i\eta I_2}
$$
here $H(k)$ is Hamiltonian which is $2\times 2$ matrix and its all elements depend upon $k$. And $I_2$ is identity matrix of order $2$. I want to take the derivative of $G^R$ with respect to $k$. As $G^R$ is a matrix, the order is important. I am not sure which of the following is correct

1. $
   \frac{d}{dk} \Big[G^R(k)\Big] = \Big[G^R(k)\Big]^2 \frac{d}{dk} \Big[H(k)\Big] 
   $
2. $
   \frac{d}{dk} \Big[G^R(k)\Big] = \Big[G^R(k)\Big] \frac{d}{dk} \Big[H(k)\Big]  \Big[G^R(k)\Big]
   $

Comment: @coudy oh! sorry for my notation. Both $\epsilon$ and $i\eta$ are multiplied with identity matrix $I_2$ of order $2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. is correct.

In general, we have for any matrix $A(x)$,
$$A(x+h)^{-1} - A(x)^{-1} = - A(x)^{-1} \Bigl(A(x+h)-A(x)\Bigr)A(x+h)^{-1}$$
Letting $h$ goes to zero gives
$${d\over dx} A^{-1}(x) = -A(x) \ {dA\over dx}(x) \ A(x).$$
In your case, $A(x) = (\epsilon + i\eta)id -H(x)$, $A' = -H$, hence the result.

Comment: Thank you so much